# Different y-limits on ggplot facet grid bar graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data:

```
    day variable      value
1  Fri     avg1 446.521127
2  Mon     avg1 461.676056
3  Sat     avg1 393.366197
4  Sun     avg1 435.985714
5  Thu     avg1 445.571429
6  Tue     avg1 441.549296
7  Wed     avg1 462.042254
8  Fri     avg2   7.442113
9  Mon     avg2   7.694648
10 Sat     avg2   6.556056
11 Sun     avg2   7.266571
12 Thu     avg2   7.426286
13 Tue     avg2   7.359577
14 Wed     avg2   7.700282
```

My issue is I want to create a bar graph using `facet_grid` displaying each set of avg data by day, but the observations are similar enough that I've found it helpful to specify the y-limits using `scale_y_continuous`.

So, if I assign my ggplot to `g <- ggplot(df, aes(x=day, y=value))`, I can get half of what I want by each of:

```
g + geom_bar(stat="identity") + facet_grid(variable~., scales="free")
```

AND

```
g + geom_bar(stat="identity") + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(300,500), oob=rescale_none)
```

However, I don't know how to use facet grid and then specify a scale_y_cont that will limit the size of separate y-axes. Is there a solution?

Comment: Are you saying that you don't want the lower y-limit of each facet to be zero?

Comment: right, I want the lower limit to be something like the 'mean' of the range

Comment: So you want the lower limit of facet `avg1` to be roughly 0.5*max(avg1) and the lower limit of facet `avg2` to be roughly 0.5*max(avg2)? I'd recommend against using a bar plot if you don't want the y-scale to go down to zero, since the relative differences between bar heights will be misleadingly large.

Comment: yes, but I don't see how I can refer to variable or value in `scale_y_continuous`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create separate y-ranges for different facets when using `geom_point`, but I don't know of a way to do it with `geom_bar`. To set specific y-ranges with `facet_wrap` and `geom_bar`, the only way I know of is to create separate plots and then put them side by side using `grid.arrange` from the `gridExtra` package. (Using a vertical scale that doesn't go down to zero will exaggerate differences between points/bars, which can be misleading, but you'll have to decide if it makes sense for your particular case.)

First, here's the `geom_point` version: The idea is to create a "dummy" data frame with lower and upper values you want for ylim and then "plot" them using `geom_blank`. `geom_blank` doesn't plot anything, but adding this geom will ensure that the axis range is what you want it to be for each facet.

```
ddummy = data.frame(day=NA, variable=rep(c("avg1", "avg2"), each=2), 
               value=c(0.5*max(df$value[df$variable=="avg1"]), 
                       1.1*max(df$value[df$variable=="avg1"]),
                       0.5*max(df$value[df$variable=="avg2"]), 
                       1.1*max(df$value[df$variable=="avg2"])))

g <- ggplot(df, aes(x=day, y=value))

g + geom_point() + 
  geom_blank(data=dummy, aes(day, value)) +
  facet_grid(variable ~ ., scales="free")
```

[image]

And here are separate plots, put together with `grid.arrange`:

```
avg1 = ggplot(df[df$variable=="avg1",], aes(x=day, y=value)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  facet_wrap(~variable) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(300,500))

avg2 = ggplot(df[df$variable=="avg2",], aes(x=day, y=value)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  facet_wrap(~variable) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(3.5,8))

gridExtra::grid.arrange(avg1, avg2, ncol=2)
```

[image]

To use `geom_segment` (per your comment) you could do this:

```
library(dplyr)

ggplot(df %>% group_by(variable) %>%
         mutate(ymin=0.5*max(value))) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=day, xend=day, y=ymin, yend=value), 
               size=5, colour=hcl(195,100,65)) + 
  facet_grid(variable ~ ., scales="free")
```

Comment: Excellent. Why isn't the y-range enforced on a bar graph as with `geom_point`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's because `geom_bar` "assumes" the bar should go down to zero, so the effective range of the "data" `geom_bar` is implicitly using is zero to max(ydata). Adding a dummy data frame with a y-range above zero doesn't change that, so it doesn't change the plot. However, if you change the `0.5` in my dummy data frame to `-0.5`, you'll see that `geom_bar` expands the y-range below zero, because you've now effectively expanded the y-range of the plot.

Comment: oh, of course. If you plot `geom_point` without the dummy, you get a similar result. I wonder if you could use `geom_segment` to plot from max(avg1/2)/2 to the value.

Comment: This is an old question and I don't have time to write a full answer, but it is possible to do this with bar graphs using the function facet_grid_sc() from package facetscales

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the `scales = 'free'` option works for me when it comes to `geom_bar` function as well. My code chunk is as follows:

```
    merged_no_country_year %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x=age, y=outcome_values/1000000)) + 
      geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="skyblue", alpha=1.0) + 
      theme_minimal() +
      facet_grid(outcome~source, scales = 'free') + 
      labs(y='people (in millions)')
```