# qplot limit of facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

Good day?
Is it possible to set ymin, ymax as 0, 800 for the upper three facets and 0, 100 for the lower three facets?

```
ssc <- data.frame(list(avg=c(1.288,1.306,1.312),cv=c(621,0.842,0.838),scr=c(1,2,1),pwr=c(1,2,3),wb=c(1,3,3)) )
ssc$scr <- factor(ssc$scr)
ssc$pwr <- factor(ssc$pwr)
ssc$wb <- factor(ssc$wb)
qplot(avg,cv,data=ssc,colour=wb)+ facet_grid(scr~pwr)
```

Comment: You can set `scales = "free_y"` in `facet_grid` together with `ylim(0, NA)`. Not exactly what you want though.

Comment: It's not possible. You will have to either use `scales = "free_y` or create two separate plots and combine them using `gridExtra::grid.arrange`.

Comment: You could [bluff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30281595/6203226) the `facet_grid` with `geom_blank`