# Reusing axes ranges from previous ggplot facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, axes

I'm trying to figure out a way to use the axes ranges from a `facet_wrap` object I created with just the data when I add glm fits, which are poor and greatly expand the axes ranges.

Here's an example

```
data <-  structure(list(ID = structure(c(14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L), levels = c("T229", "T230", "T231", "T234", 
"T235", "T236", "T237", "T243", "T244", "T246", "T247", "T257", 
"T258", "T259", "T260"), class = "factor"), x = c(35, 40, 42, 
44, 27, 35, 40, 27, 42, 44), y = c(7, 0, 0, 0, 18, 74, 45, 20, 
32, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

## Data only Plot

xlab <- "X Label"
ylab <- "Y Label"

plot_data_only <-
    ggplot(data) + 
    aes(x = x,
        y = y) +
    facet_wrap("ID", scales = "free_y") +
    geom_jitter() +
    labs(x = xlab, y = ylab,
         title = "Just the Data") 

## Plot data and model


plot_data_only +
    stat_smooth(method = "glm",
                method.args = list(
                    family = quasipoisson(link = "log"),
                    start = coefficients(glm_combined),
                    maxit = 100),
                se = FALSE,
                formula = y ~ 1 + x + I(x^2), size = 1,
                ) +
         labs(title = "Data and model fits-- oh my")
```

Here's what I get:

[image: plot_data_only]

[image: plot_data_and_poor_glm_fit]

Instead of the second plot going from 0 to 16 in the second panel, it goes from 0 to 4500!

I've tried using something like `plot_data_only$scales +`, but clearly I don't understand ggplot2 very well.

Is there an object I can extract from the original plot and reuse in the second one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually possible to copy over the exact panel parameters so that you have the same axis limits in your second plot, though it's a bit hacky:

```r
plot_with_smooth <- plot_data_only +
  stat_smooth(method = "glm", aes(group = ID),
              method.args = list(
                family = quasipoisson(link = "log"),
                maxit = 1000),
              se = FALSE,
              formula = y ~ 1 + x + I(x^2), size = 1,
  ) +
  labs(title = "Data and model fits-- oh my") 

p1 <- ggplot_build(plot_data_only)
p2 <- ggplot_build(plot_with_smooth)

p2$layout$panel_scales_y[[2]] <- p1$layout$panel_scales_y[[2]]
p2$layout$panel_params <- p1$layout$panel_params

grid::grid.draw(ggplot_gtable(p2))
```

[image]

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  I wish there was a less hacky way, but your answer deepens and expands my knowledge of ggplot2.

Comment: the line `p2$layout$panel_scales_y[[2]] <- p1$layout$panel_scales_y[[2]]` seems unnecessary, what is it supposed to do?

Comment: @mikemtnbikes it copies the y scale from the second panel to the first panel

Answer (score 0):

You can set yaxis limits by adding [`ylim()`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/lims.html) to your ggplot like this:

```
plot_data_only +
    stat_smooth(method = "glm",
                method.args = list(
                    family = quasipoisson(link = "log"),
                    start = coefficients(glm_combined),
                    maxit = 100),
                se = FALSE,
                formula = y ~ 1 + x + I(x^2), size = 1) +
    labs(title = "Data and model fits-- oh my")+
    ylim(0,20)
```

Thought using this method on `facet_wrap` leads to the yaxis scaled looking the same on both panels. If you want to set two different scales then you might want to refer to this [previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30280499/different-y-limits-on-ggplot-facet-grid-bar-graph) and decide what would be best for you.